# Check if string is contained in list element

Tags: python

I have a sample list of possible incident:

```
incident = [
    "road", "free", "block", "bumper", "accident","robbery","collapse","fire","police","flood"]
```

and i want to check if a sentence has any of this words in it.

eg. "the building is on fire"

this should return true since the list has fire in it and return false if otherwise.

I tried doing it with this method :

```
query = "@user1 @handler2 the building is on fire"

if any(query in s for s in incidentList):
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

but it always fail as oppose to when `query = "fire"`.

***Edit***

and in situation when incident contains an element say: "street fight", i want it to return true assuming the query contains either street or fight.
How do i fix this?

Comment: Should not it be `s in query` instead?

Comment: Are you OK with matching `road` when words like `broad` are present? What if a username contains one of the incident words like `@firefighter`? Wouldn't you want to be case-insensitive? Right now, `Police` would not be found...

Comment: @TimPietzcker that's true, but i can just make the everything lower case then.

Answer (score 6):

`s` refers to every incident in the list of incidents, check if `s` is in `query` instead:

```
if any(s in query for s in incidentList):
```

> and in situation when incident contains an element say: "street fight", i want it to return true assuming the query contains either street or fight. How do i fix this?

Then, either improve the `incidentList` to contain individual words only, or you should also split the `s` in the loop:

```
if any(any(item in query for item in s.split()) for s in incidentList):
```

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there, just need to do it the reverse way:

```
incident = [
    "road", "free", "block", "bumper", "accident","robbery","collapse","fire","police","flood"]

query = "@user1 @handler2 the building is on fire"

if any(s in query for s in incident):
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Which makes sense, because you want to check for every `s` in `incident` (any word, including `fire`), if that `s` (that is, `fire`) is in `query` too.

You do **not** want to say if `query` (that is, your whole sentence) is in `s` (that is, a word like `fire`)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps..

```
import sys
incident = ["road", "free", "block", "bumper", "accident","robbery","collapse","fire","police","flood", "street fight"]
sentence = "street is awesome"
sentence = sentence.split()
for word in sentence:       
    for element in incident:
        if word in element.split():
            print('True')
            sys.exit(0)
```